# Set object properties using a UISwitch in a custom cell

Tags: swift, uiswitch

I'm trying to do something that *should* be very simple, but I'm having issues due to my inexperience with Swift.

I have a `ViewController` that has a `TableView` inside of it with custom cells that are populated from an array of objects (called `allListItems`). These objects were created using `Realm Model Object`, which I'm using instead of Core Data, which I think might be pertinent. Each custom cell has a `UISwitch` in it, and ideally I'd like to set it up so that when the user toggles the `UISwitch`, it modifies the boolean `isSelected` property for that `indexPath.row`, and then appends that object to a separate array, called `selectedListItems`.

All of my searching through SO, Tuts+, and AppCoda has revealed that I should be using a protocol - delegate pattern here, with my protocol in my custom cell class and my delegate in my `ViewController` class. After flailing away at it for most of the day I haven't had any luck, however, which I think might be due to the arrays being Realm Model Objects.

As I mentioned, I'm very new to Swift and programming in general, so ELI5 responses are much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

For reference, here is my custom cell:

```
import UIKit

class AllListItemsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var toggleIsSelected: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet var listItemLabel: UILabel!

  override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the suggested protocol / delegate pattern use a callback.
This is very easy in Swift.

In the table view cell declare a optional variable with a closure

```
var callback : ((UITableViewCell, Bool) -> Void)?
```

and call it in the `IBAction` for the switch

```
@IBAction func switchChanged(sender : UISwitch) {
    callback?(self, sender.on)
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the callback

```
cell.callback = { (tableViewCell, switchState) in
  if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(tableViewCell) {
    // do something with index path and switch state
  }
}
```

To pass the cell back can be useful if the cell was moved meanwhile to get the most recent index path.

Comment: This is exactly what I was needing, thanks so much! Now I'm struggling a little bit with deleting the items from the `selectedListItems` array since I'm using `indexOf`, but that's for another SO question if I can't figure it out on my own.